# Existence of improper integrals via monotonicity and boundedness

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

Let be $f:[1,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$ monotonically decreasing and $\int\limits_1^{\infty}f(t)dt$ an improper integral. Further we can assume that $\int\limits_1^{\beta}f(t)dt\leq d$ for all $\beta\in[0,\infty)$, where $d\in\mathbb{R}$. We want to show that $\int\limits_1^{\infty}f(t)dt$ exists.

---

My approach:

We define a function $F(x):=\int\limits_1^{x}f(t)dt$. So we know that if $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}F(x)$ exists then $\int\limits_1^{\infty}f(t)dt$ exists. We know from the theory of limits that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}F(x)$ exists iff for each sequence $\left(b_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ with $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}b_n=\infty$ the sequence of the images $F(b_n)$ also converges, e.g. $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}F(b_n)=c$.

As $f(x)\geq 0$ for all $x\in [1,\infty)$, I was wondering if we can simply argue that $F(b_n)=\int\limits_1^{b_n}f(t)dt$ is monotonically increasing. This would allow us to conclude that $F(b_n)$ is convergent (monotonicity and boundedness imply convergence of sequences, aka monotone convergence theorem) and hence $\int\limits_1^{\infty}f(t)dt$ exists.

However, I am not sure about this step because if the sequence $\left(b_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is not monotonically increasing then it would not be guaranteed that $F(b_n)=\int\limits_1^{b_n}f(t)dt$ is monotonically increasing.

Am I right with my concerns? Or is it legit to argue with monotonicity and boundedness in this case?

---

**EDIT**

I think there is some ambiguity in the discussion in the comments below which causes a lot of confusion. I will clarify it a little bit. There exist at least two different versions of the monotone convergence theorem. One regards to sequences (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem) and the other one to limits of functions (see for example: [Proving a bounded monotone function has finite one-sided limits](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1841807/579544) or [Suppose that the function $f:I\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is monotonically increasing and bounded. Prove that the $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)$ exists](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1518143/579544)). The expression $F(b_n)$ defines, as mentioned above, a sequence, precisely the sequence of images of $b_n$ under the function $F(x)$. As shown in my example it is **wrong** to say that $F(b_n)$ is increasing! So we cannot apply the monotone convergence theorem (which deals with sequences).

However, the monotone convergence theorem wich regards to limits of functions requires the function to be monotonically increasing and **not** the sequence $F(b_n)$. The function $F(x)$ is clearly monotonically increasing as $f(x)\geq 0$.

So I cannot apply the monotone convergence theorem of sequences but the monotone convergence theorem of limits of functions to show the existence of the limit.

Comment: $F(b_n)$ is increasing becasue the integrand is non-negative. So your proof works fine.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy what if $b_2=3$ and $b_3=2$, then $F(b_n)=\int\limits_1^{b_n}f(t)dt$ would not be monotonously increasing, regardless of the non-negative integrand?

Comment: To show that $\lim_{x \to \infty} F(x)$ exists it is enough to consider sequences $(b_n)$ increasing to $\infty$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, but then we can't apply the monotone convergence theorem and my proof would be flawed?

Comment: Your argument is fine. Boundeness $+$ monotonicity is what gives the answer.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, as I have said before, I don't think that $F(b_b)$ is monotonously increasing and therefore it is not allowed to apply the monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: In your example you took $b_3 <b_2$. I am saying that if $b_n$ is **increasing** then $F(b_n)$ is  also increasing.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, please see my edit. Hopefully it makes clear what the problem was.

Comment: "monotonically" not "monotonously."

Comment: @DougM thanks, at least I have learned some English from that question :D